# Remove comments from text file in Java

Tags: java

Is there any easy way to remove the comments from the text file in Java.

```
now:

:-  /* #pos=1,513 */ author(A, UniqueVar1)

after:

author(A, UniqueVar1)
```

I used BufferedReader and readline to read and split the lines.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
line.replaceAll("(?:/\\*(?:[^*]|(?:\\*+[^*/]))*\\*+/)|(?://.*)|(?::-)","");
```

Comment: This will fail on multiline comments

Comment: Beware of comments inside strings as well! They don't count.